# Stack track determination and open gl dlls

Tags: opengl, stack-trace, disassembly

After being able to determine call stack successfully (in my previous questions) - I was bit puzzled with opengl drivers.

```
KERNELBASE.dll                   GlobalAlloc (00007FF995B09643)
nvoglv64.DLL                     DrvPresentBuffers (0000000054F22747)
nvoglv64.DLL                     DrvPresentBuffers (0000000054F20893)
nvoglv64.DLL                     DrvPresentBuffers (0000000054F221B2)
nvoglv64.DLL                     (0000000054A6D79A)
nvoglv64.DLL                     (0000000054BA478A)
nvoglv64.DLL                     (0000000054BA60B5)
myown.dll                        my own source code(line) (00007FF96CCB6B73)
```

What I've briefly analyzed - direct function names are defined in opengl32.dll, which is simply a router to actual implementation - which might be NVidia or ATI or other display driver manufacturer.

But implementation jumps directly into display driver provider without caring about exported symbols.

In assembly I've noticed that most of functions have simple jumps to native implementation - for example like this:

```
glDrawElements:
00007FF97F0A8D80 65 FF 24 25 98 0E 00 00 jmp         qword ptr gs:[0E98h]
```

This jump will land in nvoglv64.DLL.

But nvoglv64.DLL does not exports any useful symbols, so it's difficult to determine where execution was heading in call stack.

I theory I've could do quite trivial scan - load open32.dll, get all proc addresses (not sure if this can be done with Windows API, but I suspect so), then scan executable code at all positions, and detect such jump (65 FF 24 25 for 64-bit code)

but not sure how to extract "qword ptr gs:[0E98h]" data address without executing code.

So at the end I want to map address '0000000054BA60B5' to 'glDrawElements' symbol name.

Also may be it makes sense to contact driver manufacturer - may be they will export their symbols just for debuggability purpose. (May be with some underscore ? E.g. _glDrawElements )

What I have also understand is that NVidia does not necessarily provides .pdb's for their drivers ? May be this statement also not true.

Cross linked this question with NVidia forum as well:
https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/917471/geforce-drivers/stack-track-determination-and-open-gl-dlls/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Since graphic-card drivers under windows are proprietary I highly doubt that they will provide this information.

Comment: I'm trying to improve diagnostic level of my tool: http://www.saunalahti.fi/~tarmpika/diagnostic/ - so tool can distinguish was memory leak happening in open gl application or open gl itself.

Currently I'm analyzing rather huge amount of memory disappearing, and I suspect that opengl driver is guilty one, but this needs to be driven from formal api call sequence - was memory released from client  or not. (glGenLists, glNewList, glEndList, glDeleteLists)

Comment: They are proprietary, but there are always experts in assembly who could help me on this one.